# Could someone explain to me what tense to use?

Tags: future-time

I'll be back on set tomorrow. This will be the last time I **will play** this character.

I'll be back on set tomorrow. This will be the last time I **play** this character.

I'll be back on set tomorrow. This will be the last time I **will be playing** this character.

I'll be back on set tomorrow. This will be the last time I **am playing** this character.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for the question.

Number 1 and 3 are both fine; however, I would personally go with number 3 to indicate that "playing" the character takes some time and to emphasize duration. I searched the Internet. Most of the sentences have the same structure as number 1, but they use different verbs such as "say", "let" and "see", which don't require any kind of duration, as in:

*This will be the last time I'll let him bother me.*
*This will be the last time I'll see Bob Dylan perform.*

and some like the following sentence have the same structure as number 3.

*This will be the last time I'll be using your service.*

The verb "use" is like the verb "play" in that both can take some time. Therefore, "I'll be playing" is better in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

> I'll be back on set tomorrow.

1

> This will be the last time I **will play** this character.

2

> This will be the last time I **play** this character.

3

> This will be the last time I **will be playing** this character.

4

> This will be the last time I **am playing** this character.

I add to what @Mohsen from Iran has said.

All of your four examples are possible.
[UVIC](https://continuingstudies.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/410/grammar/410-expressing-the-future#:%7E:text=The%20Present%20Progressive%20Tense%20for,not%20happening%20at%20this%20moment.) explains the use of **present tense** for planned future events.
2.

> The **present simple** tense is used to talk about future events that have been scheduled.

> He'll be here soon. His plane **arrives** at 6:45.

4. 

> [W]e often use the **present progressive** (be + verb + ing) to talk about future events which have already been planned.

> **I'm playing** golf with some friends on Saturday.

The differences between **will** and **be going to** are further explained there, and I summarise here, with some adjustments for parallelism.

We use **will** to talk about things that we think will happen; to make formal announcements concerning future events; to make promises or offers related to the future; to state decisions concerning future events (decisions that are made while talking); or to make serious promises.

We use **be going to** to make a prediction about the future based on our sense of sight, smell, taste, hearing or touch; to talk about future events which have already been planned; or to talk about informal situations involving future actions.